# Hyperlink to a bookmark or logical page

Tags: hyperref

I know I can use `hyperref` to link to named destination or an specific physical-page withing the PDF file.

Is it possible to link to a bookmark or to an specific logical-page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) It is not possible to "link" to a bookmark.

(b) Option `pageanchor` sets page anchors (enabled by default).
  If options `hypertexnames` (true) and `plainpages` (false) are not changed, then the name of the anchor is  `page.\thepage`. This anchor is also used by `\hyperpage`, e.g. `\hyperpage{iii}` for the page with page number `iii`. The anchor name is `page.iii`.

Comment: @HeihoOberdiek is it possible to extend `hyperref` to link to a Bookmark or there are technical impediments to it?

Comment: @PauloNey If the bookmark is a link to somewhere, you can create a link that jumps to the same target, but a bookmark cannot be a link target.